# How to remove camera permissions icon in chrome browser after MediaStreams stop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, permissions, camera

After stop working with camera I still see permission icon for the camera in chrome browser. I cannot reload page after turn of the camera and I should stay on this page.

```js
    var _video = document.getElementById('video');
    var _mediaStream = null;
    navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({audio: false, video: true}).then(function (stream) {
            _mediaStream = stream;
            _video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            _video.play();
        });
    document.getElementById('stopCamera').addEventListener('click', function () {
        _video.pause();
        _video.src = '';
        _mediaStream.getVideoTracks().forEach(function (track) {
            track.stop();
        });
        _mediaStream.getAudioTracks().forEach(function (track) {
            track.stop();
        });
        _mediaStream = null;
        _video.parentNode.removeChild(_video);
    });
```

```html
<button id="stopCamera">Stop Camera</button>
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
```

Comment: the end user giveth, only the end user should be able to taketh away

Comment: have you found some solution to this? I need to revoke permissions for media access and ask again without loading page again